# Use Windows Form control in Asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, controls, windows-forms-designer

I have a Asp.net application in which I want to add functionality to allow user to attach files to a project. When user clicks on a button to attach a file, I want to show a dialog something like this to get the file as input from user (this is a snapshot of TFS's file attachment).

[image]

Is this a windows Form dialogue? If yes, how can I create a windows Form dialog inside my Asp.net application and show it in my aspx page. If its not a windows form dialog, what kind it is? Please guide.
P.S: I am new to web application development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly simpl just use **[FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**.

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUpload1"                 
     runat="server">
</asp:FileUpload>

<asp:Button id="UploadButton" 
     Text="Upload file"
     OnClick="UploadButton_Click"
     runat="server">
</asp:Button>
```

And in your backbend code you'll have

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //Do something with the uploaded files 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```